# Server Google App Engine (1.8.2) at localhost failed to start

Tags: eclipse, google-app-engine, jakarta-ee, eclipse-plugin

I am trying to create Dynamic Web Application in Eclipse on Google App Engine.

I have followed [this](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/webtoolsplatform) tutorial exactly but whenever I `Run on Server`, I get the following error. I have shown both, error log and the dialog that appears when I run my project. And apparently there is no search result after Googling this error. Any help would be appreciated in this regard. Thanks.

**UPDATE:**
Point to note here is that if I use the tutorial available [here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/gettingstarted/creating) then the project runs fine. The difference is that This way I create new project by clicking the New Web Application Project button in the toolbar:[image]

[image]

Comment: i cant see the image can may be proxy !? :)

Comment: @Shareef I have posted image here too http://postimg.org/image/nkh37p3qr/

Comment: Is there a collision of ports or something like that? Are you running something in the background? Try restarting your computer and do the same operation again. Same result?

Comment: Its a fresh installation of Windows 7 64bit, I am damn sure that no port collision is happening and nothing is running in background. And Even if it was a collision it would show port not available error right?

Comment: I am using Eclipse Junu. And I have restarted eclipse many times. But I haven't tried restarting Windows. Please remember that every thing works if I follow https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/gettingstarted/creating. But I need `Dynamic Web Application`.

Comment: make sure that tomcat port is not used and the required lib is in folder of tomcat libs

Comment: I installed Eclipse Kepler and error went away, BTW I tried fresh installation of Eclipse Junu but this error kept coming, So I think something is broken in Eclipse Junu aur google app engine plugin for eclipse junu.

Answer (score 1):

It is because your launch configuration file is corrupt.

- **location:** *WORKSPACE/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.debug.core/.launches.*

All you need to do to solve this problem is to delete the existing launch configuration (in Run > Run configurations)

More precisely: **Run > Run configurations > Web Application > right click in your project's name > Delete**